# Can a Kafka High Level Consumer be assigned to a specific Partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

Given the fact that a Consumer in Kafka can be configured to receive messages only from one partition, I haven't seen a configuration approach for this.

How do I tell a Kafka broker:

That I'm a **CONSUMER A** with this **ID**, under this **GROUP L**, subscribing to **TOPIC X**, willing to get the stream of **PARTITION A**?

And then, start another **CONSUMER B**, under **GROUP L**, which subscribes to **TOPIC X**, willing to get the stream of **PARTITION B**?

In other words, as in the scenario described by Kafka,

*How do I start a consumer subscribing to a wall feed of a specific user? Can I start a consumer when a user logs in, consumer his/her partition form the topic and send the feed to the client?*

Answer (score 0):

It seems this isn't a feature implemented in 0.7.

Have a look at this thread:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-kafka-users/201205.mbox/browser

However, it is planned for future releases:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-345
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-909

Comment: This answer is so that anybody with the same problem picks off where I ended up my research. Note that as of now, Beta 1 of 0.8 is available and we could see if these features are going to be implemented.

A low level consumer is the way to go (http://people.apache.org/~joestein/kafka-0.7.1-incubating-docs/kafka/api/FetchRequest.html) , at the loss of many provided features.

Comment: check the [Simple consumer API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) in kafka 0.8 release. As from their doc you should go for the simple consumer api when you want much fine grain control over the message e.g consuming same offset multiple times or from a specific partition etc.